# How do I provision the mLab add-on for my Heroku review app?

Tags: node.js, heroku, mlab

My Heroku review apps do not find the `MONGODB_URI` environment variable which I'm expecting to be automatically supplied by the mLab add-on as per [the documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mongolab#getting-your-connection-uri). My app has an `app.json` which specifies `mongolab` as an add-on and is a Node app so I try to access the variable via `process.env.MONGODB_URI` but it is `undefined`.

I've tried running `heroku addons:open mongolab -a my-app-pr-17` to have a look at provisioned databases but I get the message *"Couldn't find that add on"*.

The resource tab for the review app in the Heroku dashboard shows the message *"There are no add-ons for this app"*.

Running `heroku config -a my-app-pr-17` shows an empty list.

Here's my `app.json` file.

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "addons": [
    "mongolab"
  ],
  "buildpacks": [
    {
      "url": "heroku/nodejs"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm expecting that in my Node code `process.env.MONGODB_URI` is a URI with the username and password as described in [the documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mongolab#getting-your-connection-uri).

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that **`app.json` is only read when the review app is first created**. Updates to the `app.json` file are not honoured in subsequent deployments of the same review app.

In my case I had connected GitHub, opened a pull request which created a review app, and then pushed further commits to update `app.json` and add the *mongolab* add-on. I was confused when these further commits didn't create the add-on for me, but Heroku doesn't sync changes throughout the lifetime of the app.

Creating a new PR created a new review app which had the mongolab add-on automatically provisioned as I expected. I manually added the add-on to the existing review app to continue working with it.